# how simulate key press and mouse click by sendinput without setting focus to the application

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use sendinput for not focused application?
I saw some related posts using HWND, but I do not the knowledge of HWND.
Can you explain some objects and functions related to HWND in order to simulating key press and mouse click without setting focus to the application?

Comment: You should tag your question with [winapi]. You can send input to a window without it having focus. If you do not know what window to send the input to then I don't see how any function can help you.

Comment: [Answer here I think](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979055%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Thank you DrakaSAN gave me the idea of HWND.
Sendinput does not require HWND as argument so using sendinput cannot do what I want.